# Django Test Client not working with Database calls

Tags: django-testing

I'm using the `django.test.Client` to write tests for django's views

In the Django's view:

```
usr = User.objects.get(id=2)
```

It does not returns the `User` object, instead raises error `ObjectDoesNotExist`.

In dbshell same query works fine.

What's the catch here ?

Comment: it creates a new, empty database for each test, so you must load a fixture to have that record in place to perform that get. No fixture = empty db.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood i have added the fixture of User table in TestCase, but still does not work

Comment: Did you dump data to that fixture file?

Comment: @PaulCollingwood yes

Comment: well, loading data from fixtures works for me in test cases. Show your setup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a user in either the `setUp()` method of the `TestCase`, or add one in a fixture. Here's the `setUp()` version:

```
class YourTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create(
            username='someuser',
            email='someuser@example.com',
            password='password'
        )

    def test_your_code(self):
        # now you can look it up
        user = User.objects.get(username='someuser')
        self.assertEqual(user.email, 'someuser@example.com')
```

Comment: I know this is old - however, is there a way to get around this without having to manually create these users in the setUp?  For example, if our database currently has a ton of inner workings, is there a way to have django clone that DB (and test against the clone) when running the tests so we don't have to manually add potentially tons of data?

Comment: Before trying to maintain a test database, I'd try Model Mommy - http://model-mommy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html

You're setUp would look something like this:
    users = mommy.make(User, _quantity=1000)

This is the bit in the docs about that - http://model-mommy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html#more-than-one-instance

Comment: Awesome - I will definitely take a look at that. Appreciate the input on an older question!